# Building Unreal Engine from Source Error (Targeting Hololens problem.....)

Tags: build, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4

I have a problem when building Unreal Engine 4 from source code (visual studio 2019).

I have followed every instruction from UE4 documnetation.[Building Unreal Engine from Source](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProductionPipelines/DevelopmentSetup/BuildingUnrealEngine/)

Once I run "build", after some minute, following error message shows up.
(related to targeting holoLens Platform)

[image]

I have removed previous UE4 Source Code and re-downloaded and tried to install again, but same message comes out every time.
I think it is related to targeting holoLens platform, but cannot find any clue......

(Just to be sure, I am not trying to make any project related to HoloLens. The main purpose is to build Unreal Engine 4 from Source code)

If you know any solution, it would be great to hear that.